# Cleaning Urls in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

<There is more code to this but I collected Twitter data using twint. I am using Jupyter Notebooks as well. I have filtered the data that I want to keep for my graph. But in my nx node edges graph, has the full URL of the web pages. I want to get ride of the http://, https:// and the extra stuff after the .com or .org etc. I am getting the error '**DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str**' when I try to do a replace to get rid of the 'https://' in the URLs.>

```
import csv
import twint
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import nest_asyncio
import re
nest_asyncio.apply()

NWO_data = pd.read_csv("TwitterLinksNWO.csv")

NWO_data['urls'].replace('[]', np.nan, inplace=True)
NWO_data.dropna(subset=['urls'],inplace=True)
NWO_data.shape
NWO_data = NWO_data.astype({'urls': np.str}, copy=True) #This is suppose to change it from a object  data type to a string.


urlsCleaned = NWO_data[["urls"]]

print(urlsCleaned.str.replace('https://','1'))
print(urlsCleaned)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem arises because `urlsCleaned` is a `pd.DataFrame` not a `pd.Series`, to solve you have to change the line to:

```
urlsCleaned = NWO_data["urls"]
```

Note that they look **almost** the same, but in your case, it creates a `pd.DataFrame` with one column, and here it creates an `pd.Series`.

Comment: Okay, now I can clean that data of the extra stuff I do not want. My next question is once I clean the urlsCleaned to my liking how can I make those values equal the dataframe column of NWO_data["urls"]

Comment: Sorry, but it`s a SO policy to ask only one solution per question. If you want, you can ask another question but if this already solved your problem you should accept the answer